# Cloud Integration to more than one enterprise end-point

Tags: integration, ibm-cloud, hybrid, cloud-integration

I need to connect a Bluemix organisation to multiple external systems.

Can I use one Cloud Integration service Basic connector on Bluemix to connect to many on-premises end-points?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a single Basic connector to connect to multiple endpoints.

After you follow the instructions to get your connector set up, you'll want to click the arrow at the far right under the detail column:

[image: Basic Connector Details]

From there, you'll be taken to a page that lists the endpoints setup with the basic connector. You can click the add endpoints button to add as many endpoints as you would like.

Keep in mind, even though you can connect to multiple endpoints with a Basic connector, you can only have one Basic connector at a given time.

Comment: Thanks @Cody. _only have one Basic connector..._ that is one per BM organisation, right?

Comment: That's correct. The connectors are stored based on your organization id, so you will all see the same Basic connector in that BM org.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Integration depends on your end points.

If you have ssh endpoint Basic Connector works but it has limitation of 5 Connection free. There after you are charged in Bluemix.

Where as if you are endpoints are API's suggested connector is Standard Connector as it works on https.

Comment: Yes but standard connection requires Cast Iron Live account. The HTTP/S connection is between Bluemix and APIs defined in Cast Iron Live.

Comment: Further, the price is per end point connection regardless of the type of connector.